# Extracting String between two special characters and replacing it with new string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, scripting, python-re

I am trying to extract a string between two characters and replace it with a new string in every occurance of old string in a file .

Example :

Str1= "portid.router.address_location"

str2= "$addressmap= portid.ipaddress"

Str1 and Str2 are part of single file . Also, str1 and str2 has numerous occurrences in my text file and I need to replace each occurrence of "portid" string with a string called "devicenumber' .

Correction to my question : portid variable is not stable one . port id variable will be keep changing for each file . Example : "portid_id6_add7" in one file and "portid_id100_add7"

Comment: What was the result of what you have tried? Did it work? If not, what went wrong? What is your question?

Comment: It seems like a RegEx (Regular Expression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression ) might be what you're looking for. It's hard to say though because your question could use a little more detail about the context of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `regex` module in python specifically then try something like to replace the occurence of a particular string with something else:

```
import re

lst = ['portid.router.address_location', '$addressmap= portid.ipaddress']
regex = re.compile('portid')

for string in lst:
   regex.sub('devicenumber', string)
```

Put this into your python shell and you will see every modified string.